# Need help in making search filter and dropdown bind with multiple values in list

Tags: c#, .net

I have one list which contains list of Students and Employees , both have ID and Name .

I have to show them in dropdown as EmpName-StudentName , please help me to concatenate both .

And when I click search I need one ID which can search both combination in drop.

Help me to build this logic in C#

Comment: What code have you written so far ?

Comment: @KobyDouek koby I got all  values in a list , but able to show only one value in dropdown but not concatinated value , search condition I have not started

Comment: No one can help you unless you edit your question and add the code you are using. I don't even know if this is a WebForm or a WindowsForm, What are the controls names etc. Please add your code section in which you have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not written any code neither you have indicated your project type, I'm going to answer for the very basic type.

If you need a formatted output of a type, then try overriding your `ToString()` method.

For Example

```
public class MyCustomType
{
   public string Employee {get; set;}
   public string Student {get; set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format("{0} - {1}",Employee, Student);
   }
}
```

Now binding to `MyCustomType` will show you EmpName-StudentName in your display.

Comment: I like that you're taking advantage of `ToString()` override. Fun Fact: visual studio debugger watch window uses an object's `ToString()` as it's displayed value.